# Crypto currency or DAO (or both) to support a growing franchise business

Tags: contract-development, dao

The information on the Ethereum site is clear and well formed, I am probably slow at getting it...

I want to issue a new crypto currency (named HoC) for our business to support a franchise model. However, after visiting the site I am not sure whether I need the Crypto-Currency or the DAO or perhaps both?

Currently, our team builds a tool and uses it to build mobile apps for clients. Our vision is to found more teams that will use the same tool in a franchise model, meaning a small percentage from each team's income will be payed for the services of supplying the tool and clients.

The crypto-currency is meant to serve the project in different ways:

1. **Incentive for the teams**
   Each new team will receive a fixed amount which will be divided monthly (cliff + vesting). This may increase commitment for the project.
2. **Create an inter-team economy**
   Buying / selling / good-will-tips within the project's members.
3. **Special Rewards** Allow the core team to give special bonuses to clients, teams or helpers.
4. **Allow voting rights** Team members can vote on different issues regarding the project, the tool's development etc. Each member's voting weight is proportional to his or her holdings.

A schematic drawing of the business' long-term vision (2017):

[image: vision for our business]

It seems articles 1-3 can be done on top of Ethereum with the CryptoCurrency code while 4 requires DAO. Which way should I go?

**Status note:** I have downloaded the wallet and started mining Ether on the Testing environment.

Comment: I don't see how 4 and 1-3 exclude each other. You don't need a DAO to have voting abilities, but if you have a contract or a token which enables voting somehow, it can be defined as a DAO.

Comment: I see. So DAO is more of an academic term to describe a contract which consists of voting capabilities, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need DAO yourself. You are free to craft your own Ethereum smart contracts with voting rights, rewards and features you choose. Basically DAO itself is just bunch of Ethereum smart contracts.

Comment: So the DAO code in the Etherium site is just a template designed to spark people's imagination about what is possible?

Comment: Exactly. You got it :)